# innerHTML adds text but not html tags

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, innerhtml

First off sorry for this beginner question but I just recently learned JavaScript and I am now learning to develop Windows 8 apps. Here is the code in question:

```
        var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
        id('numberList').innerHTML = '<ul>';
        for (var x in numbers) {
            id('numberList').innerHTML += '<li>' + x + '</li>';
        }
        id('numberList').innerHTML = '</ul>';
```

I have this in the "ready" function (for any Windows 8 developers) in my JS file and 'numbersList' refers to a section tag in the body (of the HTML file). The list does not show up at all when I am running the app. However when I simply try to add text instead of a list like so

```
       id('numberList').innerHTML = 'hello';
```

the text does show up. Could there be a problem with the way I am trying to insert the html elements?

Comment: In addition to the answers: do not use a for..in loop with an array, use a regular for(;;). If the array prototype was changed (by you or a third party), that can cause errors.

Comment: Only now saw this. Thanks bfavaretto. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't add pieces of illegal HTML like that.  A `<ul>` tag with no `</ul>` is illegal.  Build the entire HTML string in a string variable and then add one piece of legal HTML or build individual DOM elements, put the content in them and add them to the DOM.

Further, you don't iterate an array with `for (var x in numbers)` as that iterates properties of an object, not just array elements and, while it will work in some circumstances, is generally a bad practice that you should not use.

You can fix those errors and build up a single HTML string and then add it once at the end like this:

```
    var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    var str = '<ul>';
    for (var x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++) {
        str += '<li>' + numbers[x] + '</li>';
    }
    str += '</ul>';
    id('numberList').innerHTML = str;
```

For completeness, you could also build individual DOM elements:

```
    var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    var ul = document.createElement("ul"), li, tx;
    for (var x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++) {
        li = document.createElement("li");
        tx = document.createTextNode(numbers[x]);
        li.appendChild(tx);
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }
    var parent = id('numberList');
    parent.innerHTML = "";
    parent.appendChild(ul);
```

You may also want to note that the code you original wrote was not retrieving the array elements `numbers[x]`, but was using the array indexes `x` (which happen to be the same as the content so you wouldn't notice a difference in your sample code).  Since that's probably not what you intended, you probably want to fix that too.

Comment: No!  Do not manually build HTML with variable data.  Create elements and set the innerText on them instead.

Comment: @Brad - why?  Either method is valid.  Which is best depends upon the circumstance.

Comment: You plan on escaping all of your variable text data for HTML yourself?  Why would you do that?  Creating elements and setting their text ensures that this is not a problem, and is the proper way to go.  This is especially true with data that can come from the outside... you don't want to open yourself up to XSS!

Comment: @Brad, the variable data here is just a known number.  There's no problem with that.  You are free to offer an answer that creates element individually if you want.

Comment: The question of sticking numbers in is obviously an example, and not the final intent.

Comment: @Brad - which is best depends upon the situation.  There's nothing wrong with using `innerHTML` in many circumstances.  In fact, it's often faster when there are lots of elements.  I won't argue this with you any more.  My answer is simple and works.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `innerHTML`.  That's not what I'm trying to tell you.  The issue is with using arbitrary text data in an HTML context.  **Absolutely** it depends on the situation, which neither you or I know, which is why I put it in the comment in the first place, since you failed to include this information in your answer.

Comment: My answer now contains both HTML string building and DOM element creation options.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 5):

You should never use `+=` with `innerHTML`. Instead, build the string and then put it in all at once, otherwise the engine will try to correct your incomplete HTML.

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5], str;
str = "<ul>";
for( var x in numbers) str += "<li>"+x+"</li>";
str += "</ul>";
id("numberList").innerHTML = str;
```

With that being said, a "better" way to do it would be as follows:

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5], ul = document.createElement('ul');
for( var x in numbers) ul.appendChild(document.createElement('li')).appendChild(document.createTextNode(x));
var nl = id("numberList");
while(nl.firstChild) nl.removeChild(nl.firstChild);
nl.appendChild(ul);
```

Comment: Could you fix the array iteration part also?

Comment: Thank you for your help! Both answers were great but thanks for inclusion of example code though if you could explain the second "better way" that would be wonderful.